# Interactive Game of Life in Java

Tags: java, arrays, processing, interactive, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to write an interactive game of life where i can manually insert gliders in the game field.
How i want it to work is i have a glider button and after i press it i can move my cursor to where i want glider to be set on the grid and after i click on the grid glider integrates in the game of life. 
I'm using processing, and i'm using this sketch as a start up code. http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/95216

This is the code to create new cells on mouse press (one at the time)

```
// Create  new cells manually on pause
  if (pause && !gliderSelected && mousePressed) {
    // Map and avoid out of bound errors
    int xCellOver = int(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, width/cellSize));
    xCellOver = constrain(xCellOver, 0, width/cellSize-1);
    int yCellOver = int(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, height/cellSize));
    yCellOver = constrain(yCellOver, 0, height/cellSize-1);

    // Check against cells in buffer
    if (cellsBuffer[xCellOver][yCellOver]==1) { // Cell is alive
      cells[xCellOver][yCellOver]=0; // Kill
      fill(dead); // Fill with kill color
    }
    else { // Cell is dead
      cells[xCellOver][yCellOver]=1; // Make alive
      fill(alive); // Fill alive color
    }
  } 
  else if (pause && !mousePressed) { // And then save to buffer once mouse goes up
    // Save cells to buffer (so we operate with one array keeping the other intact)
    for (int x=0; x<width/cellSize; x++) {
      for (int y=0; y<height/cellSize; y++) {
        cellsBuffer[x][y] = cells[x][y];
      }
    }
  }
```

Glider shape is :

OXO 
OOX 
XXX

where O is a dead cell and X is an alive cell.

```
  //create gliders on press
  if (pause && gliderSelected && mousePressed) {
    // Map and avoid out of bound errors
    int xCellOver = int(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, width/cellSize));
    xCellOver = constrain(xCellOver, 0, width/cellSize-1);
    int yCellOver = int(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, height/cellSize));
    yCellOver = constrain(yCellOver, 0, height/cellSize-1);

    //here i thought of maybe creating an array of cells that map the glider and then running a loop to change the grid cell status according to the glider array 


  }
```

I'm not sure how to make an array that will store the glider cell locations. Each cell is a 10 pixel square, so i know how to map it if i wanted to just build it, but not sure how to stick it in the array and then integrate it in the grid.

Comment: Create an array that stores the cell as a 2D coordinate (x, y). x, y is the location of the top left of the glider instance to be drawn. I suggest this rather than working out the middle of the glider as 10, 10 doesn't have a nice centre ([5, 5], [5, 6], [6, 6] and [6, 5] are the four centrepoints).

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things in play here, how to change the cells from dead to alive in a grid, and also how to display the change before you do it. The array "gliderArray" stores your glider shape, and that is applied over the grid by going over the array and replacing the underlying grid with whatever is in the array...
As for the display, you either have to make a different state for the cells where it is displayed that they are going to change, or redraw their rectangles... This solution is the second way...

```
void draw() {

  //Draw grid
  for (int x=0; x<width/cellSize; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<height/cellSize; y++) {
      if (cells[x][y]==1) {
        fill(alive); // If alive
      }
      else {
        fill(dead); // If dead
      }
      rect (x*cellSize, y*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
    }
  }
  // Iterate if timer ticks
  if (millis()-lastRecordedTime>interval) {
    if (!pause) {
      iteration();
      lastRecordedTime = millis();
    }
  }
  //Glider shape is :
  //OXO
  //OOX
  //XXX
  //where O is a dead cell and X is an alive cell.
  int [][] gliderArray = new int [][] {
    { 0, 1, 0 }
    , 
    { 0, 0, 1 }
    , 
    { 1, 1, 1 }
  };
  // Create  new cells manually on pause
  if (pause) {
    // Map and avoid out of bound errors
    int xCellOver = int(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, width/cellSize));
    xCellOver = constrain(xCellOver, 0, width/cellSize-1);
    int yCellOver = int(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, height/cellSize));
    yCellOver = constrain(yCellOver, 0, height/cellSize-1);
    if (glider) {
      // Map again because glider takes +- 1 cells on each direction
      xCellOver = constrain(xCellOver, 1, width/cellSize-2);
      yCellOver = constrain(yCellOver, 1, height/cellSize-2);
    }
    if (mousePressed) {
      // Check against cells in buffer
      if (!glider) {
        if (cellsBuffer[xCellOver][yCellOver]==1) { // Cell is alive
          cells[xCellOver][yCellOver]=0; // Kill
          fill(dead); // Fill with kill color
        }
        else { // Cell is dead
          cells[xCellOver][yCellOver]=1; // Make alive
          fill(alive); // Fill alive color
        }
      } 
      else {
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
          for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
            cells[xCellOver+j][yCellOver+i] = gliderArray[i+1][j+1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      for (int x=0; x<width/cellSize; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<height/cellSize; y++) {
          cellsBuffer[x][y] = cells[x][y];
          if (glider && x >= xCellOver-1 && x <= xCellOver+1 && y >= yCellOver-1 && y <= yCellOver+1) {
            for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
              for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
                if (x == xCellOver+j && y == yCellOver+i) fill(gliderArray[i+1][j+1] == 1? color(255, 125, 0) : dead);
              }
            }
            rect (x*cellSize, y*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
          } 
          else if (x == xCellOver && y == yCellOver) {
            fill(cellsBuffer[x][y] == 1? color(0,0,255) : color(255, 125, 0));
            rect (x*cellSize, y*cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will also need a global boolean:

```
boolean glider = false;
```

and another check in void keyPressed()

```
if (key == 'g') glider = !glider;
```